# Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up on running ng e2e Protractor test

Tags: angular, protractor

I was trying to run protractor tests in my system, I'm getting the following error on running ng e2e

```
webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
  i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
events.js:167
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up
  at ClientRequest.onError (d:\CONDUCKTORUI\conducktor\duckweb\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
  at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
  at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
  at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:433:9)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1098:12)
  at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
  at Request.onRequestError (d:\CONDUCKTORUI\conducktor\duckweb\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
  at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
  at ClientRequest.onError (d:\CONDUCKTORUI\conducktor\duckweb\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:179:21)
  at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
  [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
  at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
```

Most of solutions I found online on this topic are related to setting the proxy, my proxy settings are null and the internet is not connected through a proxy. Can someone help me with this issue.

Please note the test cases are written for my angular application.

Comment: `ng e2e` updates webdriver every time defaultly, please try its cmd option to turn off webdriver update and run `webdriver-manager update ...` prior to `ng e2e` when you intend to update webdriver or for the first install.

Comment: webdriver-manager command is coming unrecognized

Comment: should be `node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update <options>` or you can add a cmd in `scripts` of `package.json`, like `"wdupdate": "webdriver-manager update <options>"` and execute `npm run wdupdate` to update webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webdriver manager needs to be updated correctly, try using,

```
"webdriver-update": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
```

in your package.json under `scripts`